# Deriving `Eq` for a data type based on a type family in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-families, deriving

I'm working with type-level programming in Haskell and have encountered an issue with deriving an `Eq` instance for a data type based on a type family.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, DeriveGeneric #-}

data MyKind = Value1 | Value2
  deriving (Eq)

type family MyTypeFamily (k :: MyKind) :: * where
  MyTypeFamily 'Value1 = String
  MyTypeFamily 'Value2 = [Int]

data MyType (k :: MyKind) = MyType (MyTypeFamily k)
  deriving (Eq)
```

When attempting to compile this, I receive the following error:

```
• No instance for (Eq (MyTypeFamily k))
        arising from the first field of ‘MyType’ (type ‘MyTypeFamily k’)
```

My goal is to derive separate `Eq` and other instances for each value of `MyKind`, without manually writing them out. Since the options for `MyKind` are finite and all resolve to a type with `Eq` instance, this feels like it should be possible. I tried using quantified constraints, but received an error about an illegal type synonym family application.

Is there a way in Haskell to derive separate instances based on a type family without manually writing them out or specifying each kind value individually? If not is there a counterexample, why it can't be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `StandaloneDeriving` will get you where you need to go (untested):

```
deriving instance Eq (MyTypeFamily k) => Eq (MyType k)
```

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees... Thank you!